# Jailbroken iPhone 5

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone, error

My friend in 2014 (Feb) jailbroke my phone and I never updated it again as I have no laptop. I decided I wanted to remove jailbreak because all my apps will not run on my software 7.0.4
I tried to restore it from a friends laptop with the up to date iTunes but it keeps coming up with an error. 1167 I think it is. 
I've tried holding buttons down to make it go into recovery mode but it comes up with error and never works ? I done no what else to do ?

Comment: I did some google and I couldn't find any Error 1167 (confirm with your friend please), however it may be error 1667, which is a case of a faulty Mac or iDevice, or 1611, which is a security software issue. – In other words, Confirm with your friend what error number it is!

Comment: Are you trying to restore to iOS 7.0.4? Because you can't do that. You can only restore to the latest version of iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a list of error messages that come up when restoring iOS.  That number isn't in the list.  Verify the error you are receiving and compare it with the list on [Apple's KB for restoring iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204770).

Also, you can look in the console.app while trying to restore.  It may give you more information about why it is failing.

Comment: @MrU - You commented at the same time I was writing my answer.